# How do I access the value I set in c:set in a scriptlet?

Tags: jsp

I have a JSP fragment that looks like this

```
<%@ tag
  display-name="Amount"
  pageEncoding="utf-8"
  description="Take an amount in either accounting or standard negative value notation and display it in the accounting amount format."
  trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true"
  import="java.math.BigDecimal"
%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<c:set var="value">
  <jsp:attribute name="value"><jsp:doBody/></jsp:attribute>
</c:set>
<fmt:formatNumber pattern="#,##0.00#;(#,##0.00#)">
  <jsp:attribute name="value"><%=BigDecimal.valueOf(pageContext.getProperty("value").toPlainString()%></jsp:attribute>
</fmt:formatNumber>
```

I am having trouble getting the value of `value` in the JSP scriptlet (getting compile errors)

Answer (score 0):

pageContext is not available in the .tag file, instead there's something called `jspContext` that contains the data.  Here's the full .tag code

```
<%@ tag
  display-name="Amount"
  pageEncoding="utf-8"
  description="Take an amount in either accounting or standard negative value notation and display it in the accounting amount format."
  trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true"
  import="java.math.BigDecimal"
%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<c:set var="value">
  <jsp:attribute name="value"><jsp:doBody/></jsp:attribute>
</c:set>
<c:choose>
  <c:when test="${empty value}">---</c:when>
  <c:otherwise>
    <fmt:formatNumber pattern="#,##0.00#;(#,##0.00#)">
      <jsp:attribute name="value"><%=new BigDecimal(((String)jspContext.getAttribute("value")).trim()).toPlainString()%></jsp:attribute>
    </fmt:formatNumber>
  </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```